# Determine If Variable Is Present in an Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I determine if a variable `status` is present in the array and display it once only?

```
const responses = [
    {
        "productName": "Required"
    },
    null,
    {
        "status": "Remove invalid product"
    },
    {
        "status": "Remove invalid product"
    }
]


<div>{responses[2]?.status}</div>
```

**Expected Output**

```
Remove invalid product
```

Comment: It looks like you have to filter the array and check. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What variable ?

Comment: @Bergi. `status`

Comment: That's a property, not a variable. So you're trying to determine whether the array contains one (or more) objects that have a `.status` property? And then display the first of them?

Comment: @Bergi. Yes thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with only one function, `Array.find()`. We can do this by checking if it is equal to the `Remove invalid product` inside the function. See the example below.

```js
const responses = [{
    "productName": "Required"
},
null,
{
    "status": "Remove invalid product"
},
{
    "status": "Remove invalid product"
}
];

console.log(responses.find(status => status?.status === 'Remove invalid product')?.status ? responses.find(status => status?.status === 'Remove invalid product').status : "No invalid product found");
```

**Hoped this helped!**

Comment: There's a syntax error if I do this `<div>{responses.find(status => status?.status === 'Remove invalid product').status)}</div>`

Comment: What exactly is the error? @Joseph

Comment: See it here. https://codesandbox.io/s/white-dust-yv9pp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What if there is no object with `status` property? Try this input data: `responses = [{"productName": Required"}]`

Comment: @Joseph There is no error with my code. If paste the code into your sample at code sandbox which you posted in the other answer, you have an extra `)` at the end of your code.

Comment: @AlexandrBelan I updated my code to handle those times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `array.find()`. Try this code it's help you !

```
function App() {
  const responses = [
    {
      "productName": "Required"
    },
    null,
    {
      "status": "Remove invalid product"
    },
    {
      "status": "Remove invalid product"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div> checkResponses : {responses.find(x => { if (x && x.status == "Remove invalid product") return x.status }).status}</div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Can you convert to es6?

Comment: I find this loop kind of overkill, you can do this in one line of code. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @Joseph I convert my answer to ES6 try again !

Comment: is there a shorter version of this?

Comment: I think no. this is a better for you !

Answer (score -2):

**strong text**

```
const responses = [
    {
        "productName": "Required"
    },
    null,
    {
        "status": "Remove invalid product"
    },
    {
        "status": "Remove invalid product"
    }
];

console.log(responses.find(variable => variable?.hasOwnProperty('status'))?.status);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Try adding a description of what you added and maybe even a code snippet.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.